# Need to write driver for USB peripheral device?

Tags: windows, usb, driver, device-driver

I'm working on designing a USB peripheral which will occasionally connect to a Windows PC, and transfer a few KB of data in each direction. There will be a custom PC application that controls the data transfers, using a proprietary protocol (i.e. for the USB payloads).

I see at the following link that Microsoft describes *how* to write a driver for a USB device. But do I need one?

[Developing Windows client drivers for USB devices](https://web.archive.org/web/20170409221910/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh406260(v=vs.85).aspx)

The PC application is the only application that we intend to know how to communicate with the device, so there's no need for a driver from an application sharing standpoint.

Can I just bake the custom protocol directly into the application, have the application speak "raw USB" to the device, and do without a separate driver?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"raw USB", no, you can't do that from an application.

But because you control the device also, you can make it appear as one of the device classes for which Windows provides a device driver that's generic enough to do just about anything you want.

Those device classes are HID (Human Interface Device) and "WinUSB".  Of these, HID is cross-platform but more limited in capability, WinUSB allows high performance data transfers as well as interrupt endpoints.

Instructions for setting up your device's string descriptors so that Windows automatically binds it to the WinUSB driver are [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh450799(v=vs.85).aspx)

> A WinUSB device is a Universal Serial Bus (USB) device whose firmware defines certain Microsoft operating system (OS) feature descriptors that report the compatible ID as `"WINUSB"`.
>
> The purpose of a WinUSB device is to enable Windows to load Winusb.sys as the device's function driver without a custom INF file. For a WinUSB device, you are not required to distribute INF files for your device, making the driver installation process simple for end users.

Comment: I found this informative, too. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinUSB

Comment: why are people so scared about writing device drivers? What is so complicated about it? Certainly a driver won't be 100,000s of lines of code right?

Comment: @quantum231 many people are not very comfortable in dealing with hardware phrases, and driver development is full of these phrases.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin: I don't think it has anything to do with "hardware phrases", but the fact that writing and debugging kernel code is hard.  Any mistake can crash the whole computer (and erase any trace of the events leading up to the crash).  You can only use kernel APIs, not the rich set of libraries that applications typically use.  Debugging tools for the kernel don't have a lot of the nice features such as data tooltips that pop up when you hover over a variable name in the code.

Comment: @BenVoigt Windows has had support for user-mode drivers for over a decade. You might not be able to make application calls but you certainly aren't limited to kernel procedures anymore.

Answer (score 3):

There is another way with **no need to write driver** to write what You want to device using WriteFile function:WinUSB, how to do this:

- Include WinUsb.h
- Add WinUsb.lib to the list of linked libraries.
- in Usb100.h some macros.
- Use the device interface GUID to obtain the device path. The correct GUID is the one that you specified in the INF that was used to install WinUsb.sys.
- Get a handle to the device information set by passing the device interface GUID that you defined in the INF to SetupDiGetClassDevs. The function returns an HDEVINFO handle.
- Call SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces to enumerate the system’s device interfaces and obtain information on your device interface.
- Call SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail to get detailed data for the device interface.
- Call the GetDevicePath function to obtain the device path.
- Pass the device path to CreateFile to obtain a file handle for the device. **Use ReadFile and Write File to communicate with device!**
- Pass the file handle to WinUsb_Initialize to initialize WinUSB and obtain a WinUSB handle. You use the device’s WinUSB handle to identify the device when you call WinUSB API functions, not the device’s file handle.

For more advanced solutions - use functions:

- WinUsb_QueryDeviceInformation to obtain the device’s speed.
- WinUsb_QueryInterfaceSettings to obtain the corresponding interface descriptors. The WinUSB handle corresponds to the first interface.
- WinUsb_QueryPipe gets information about each endpoint.
- WinUsb_WritePipe writes the buffer to the device  - default behavior: zero-length writes are forwarded down the stack. If the transfer length is greater than a maximum transfer length, WinUSB divides the request into smaller requests of maximum transfer length and submits them serially.
- more functions and info: http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/c/5/9c5b2167-8017-4bae-9fde-d599bac8184a/winusb_howto.docx

For debugging purposes You probably need:
 winusbtrace_tool  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/usbcoreblog/2010/02/05/how-to-generate-and-view-a-winusb-debug-trace-log/; 
Wireshark https://www.wireshark.org with USBPcap plugin.

Other Example:
http://searchingforbit.blogspot.com/2012/04/winusb-communication-with-stm32-part-1.html.
Sample template comes with Visual Studio.

You need also have knowledge of writing .inf files.

Another easy way to communicate with USB - libusb-win32 https://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb-win32/

My simple console app sends chunks to device (raw data write immediately to device bypassing the stack):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <SetupAPI.h>
#include <Hidsdi.h> 
#include <devguid.h> 
#include <winusb.h>
#include <usb.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "hid.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "setupapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "winusb.lib")
#include <iUString.h> 


iString<char> DevicePath;
bool                    WinusbHandle_Open=false;
bool                    DeviceHandle_Open = false;
WINUSB_INTERFACE_HANDLE WinusbHandle;
HANDLE                  DeviceHandle;
UCHAR usb_out_buffer[64];
DEFINE_GUID(GUID_DEVCLASS_WINUSB, 0x88bae032L, 0x5a81, 0x49f0, 0xbc, 0x3d, 0xa4, 0xff, 0x13, 0x82, 0x16, 0xd6);
DEFINE_GUID(GUID_DEVCLASS_STL, 0xf177724dL, 0x74d3, 0x430e, 0x86, 0xb5, 0xf0, 0x36, 0x89, 0x10, 0xeb, 0x23);
GUID winusb_guid;
GUID stl_guid;

bool connectusb();
void  disconnectusb();




int main()
{
    DWORD n;
    DWORD   numEvents;
    HANDLE rHnd;    

WinusbHandle_Open = false;
DeviceHandle_Open = false;
winusb_guid = GUID_DEVCLASS_WINUSB;
stl_guid = GUID_DEVCLASS_STL;
usb_out_buffer[0] = 0;
usb_out_buffer[1] = 1;
usb_out_buffer[2] = 2;
usb_out_buffer[3] = 3;

ULONG bytesWritten;
ULONG timeout;
timeout = 100;
rHnd = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

WinUsb_SetPipePolicy(WinusbHandle, 0x01, PIPE_TRANSFER_TIMEOUT, sizeof(ULONG), &timeout);

timeout = TRUE;
WinUsb_SetPipePolicy(WinusbHandle, 0x01, AUTO_CLEAR_STALL, sizeof(ULONG), &timeout);


timeout = TRUE;
WinUsb_SetPipePolicy(WinusbHandle, 0x01, RAW_IO, sizeof(ULONG), &timeout);//Bypasses queuing and error handling to boost performance for multiple read requests.


while (true)
{
if ((!WinusbHandle_Open) || (!WinusbHandle_Open)) { if (!connectusb())Sleep(2000); }
if ((!WinusbHandle_Open) || (!WinusbHandle_Open))continue;

bytesWritten = 0;
if (!WinUsb_WritePipe(WinusbHandle, 0x01, &usb_out_buffer[0], 2, &bytesWritten, NULL))
{
    n = GetLastError();
disconnectusb();
}
Sleep(2000);
}
disconnectusb();
return 0;
}




bool connectusb()
{
    BOOL                             bResult = FALSE;
    HDEVINFO                         deviceInfo;
    SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA         interfaceData;
    PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA detailData = NULL;
    DWORD n;
    SP_DEVINFO_DATA devinfo;
    BYTE devdetailbuffer[4096];
    bool found;

    deviceInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&stl_guid, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);
    if (deviceInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) { return false; }

    found = false;
    for (n = 0;; n++)
    {

        interfaceData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);

        if (!SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(deviceInfo, NULL, &stl_guid, n, &interfaceData))
        {
            n = GetLastError();
            break;
        }




        detailData = (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA)devdetailbuffer;
        detailData->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);
        devinfo.cbSize = sizeof(devinfo);
        if (!SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(deviceInfo, &interfaceData, detailData, sizeof(devdetailbuffer), NULL, &devinfo)) { printf("SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail: %u\n", GetLastError()); break; }
        if (IsEqualGUID(devinfo.ClassGuid, winusb_guid))
        {
            if ((-1 != iStrPos(detailData->DevicePath, "VID_0483")) || (-1 != iStrPos(detailData->DevicePath, "vid_0483")))
            {
                if ((-1 != iStrPos(detailData->DevicePath, "PID_576B")) || (-1 != iStrPos(detailData->DevicePath, "pid_576b")))
                {

                    DevicePath = detailData->DevicePath;
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }



SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(deviceInfo);
if (!found)return false;


DeviceHandle = CreateFile(DevicePath.Buffer() ,
    GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,
    FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
    NULL);

if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == DeviceHandle) {
    n = GetLastError();
}

if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == DeviceHandle) return false;
DeviceHandle_Open = true;



if (!WinUsb_Initialize(DeviceHandle, &WinusbHandle))
 {
     n = GetLastError();
     CloseHandle(DeviceHandle); DeviceHandle_Open = false;
     return false;
 }



WinusbHandle_Open = true;
return true;
}

void  disconnectusb()
{
    if (WinusbHandle_Open) { WinUsb_Free(WinusbHandle); WinusbHandle_Open = false; }
    if (DeviceHandle_Open) { CloseHandle(DeviceHandle); DeviceHandle_Open = false; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Making your firmware to be enumerated as a WINUSB (winusb generic driver) device** makes life easier.

I believe it'd be clear if you have a demo and code so I made one for you :)

My **KEIL project** using the **STM32F4 Discovery** board working with **WINUSB** as an **USB CDC device**. You can see more information and have **the source code from [my GitHub](https://github.com/MouChiaHung/STM32F4).**