# How to work with WinUSB?

Tags: usb, stm32, cdc, winusb

This is a follow-up to my previous question, [Need to write driver for USB peripheral device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38529675/need-to-write-driver-for-usb-peripheral-device)

### Background

I'm working on designing a USB peripheral using an STM32 microcontroller (bare metal / no OS). The device will occasionally be connected to a Windows PC, and transfer a few KB of data in each direction. There will be a custom PC application that controls the data transfers, using a proprietary protocol (i.e. for the USB payloads).

The PC will always be the master (initiator) - it'll send commands, and the device will issue responses, with up to a few hundred bytes of data going in either direction in a single command or response. I think I'll want to use USB Bulk Transfer mode.

### Option 1 - USB CDC

From what I understand, one option is I could use the USB Communications Device Class (CDC). On the device side, I could use sample code from ST for the USB CDC, e.g. from [STM32Cube](http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/embedded-software/mcus-embedded-software/stm32-embedded-software/stm32cube-embedded-software/stm32cubef0.html). On the PC side, the device would present as a Virtual COM Port (VCP). Then in software I'd basically have a raw, bidirectional stream, on top of which I'd have to define my messsage formats, commands, etc.

1. Have I explained this correctly?

### Option 2 - WinUSB

I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around exactly what this is, and how to work with it.

2. What is the relationship of WinUSB to USB device classes? It seems to function as a "generic" USB class, but I can't find any documentation that spells it out as such.
3. Does WinUSB provide any built-in message delimiters? e.g. Does [WinUsb_WritePipe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540322(v=vs.85).aspx) send the contents of the buffer down to the device as an atomic unit? Or do I just get raw streams like a VCP/UART?
4. How does one implement WinUSB on the device? Is there sample code available? (Preferably for STM32.)

### Choosing

5. What are the relevant considerations in choosing between options 1 and 2 for my application?

Comment: There is another option of libusb. You can setup custom descriptors in your device that just create a bulk endpoint, or even just use the control endpoint if your data isn't too large. libusb provides a pretty easy API for then sending/receiving packets over the endpoints.

Comment: @rjp, is libusb analogous to WinUSB?

Comment: I found it more accessible than WinUSB, and it is a cross-platform API, but the same function essentially.

Comment: LibUsb wraps WinUSB. But I've had luck getting LibUsb to work yet I can't get raw WinUsb calls to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Yes, you described USC CDC ACM correctly.
2. WinUSB exists to support devices that do not have a particular device class.  If your device implements a device class such as Human Interface Device, Mass Storage Device, or Communications Device (CDC), you can just use the drivers that come with your operating system to talk to that device.  If you want a more customizable and flexible USB interface that doesn't conform to one of those classes, you can use WinUSB to talk to your device.  You could also write your own driver if you want, but that is going to be a lot of work and I wouldn't recommend it.  Some people have written drivers that are alternatives to WinUSB: you can look up libusbK, libusb0.sys, and UsbDK for examples.  WinUSB has the advantage that it comes with Windows so I wouldn't use one of those other drivers unless it has a specific feature you really need.
3. I believe that `WinUSB_WritePipe` sends the data as a single USB *transfer*.  A *transfer* has a specific definition in the USB specification.  You can tell when a transfer ends because you will get a short packet at the end of the transfer.  A short packet is a packet that is smaller than the maximum packet size of the endpoint, and it could possibly be zero-length.  You should double check whether that is actually true though; try sending a transfer that is a multiple of the maximum packet size and make sure that Windows sends a zero-length packet at the end of that.  By the way, you should consider sending your data as a control transfer or series of control transfers on endpoint 0.  Control transfers have a built-in concept of a request and a response to the request.  Despite the name, control transfers can be used to transfer large amounts of data; they are commonly used in the USB bootloaders (see the DFU class).  Another advantage of using control transfers instead of non-zero endpoints is that you don't have to add extra endpoint descriptors and initialize the endpoints in your firmware.  Your USB stack should have the machinery for handling custom control transfers and you should be able to make custom control transfers just by writing a few callback functions.
4. To implement WinUSB on the device side, you would need to write your own USB descriptors and then use low-level USB transfer commands to read and write data from endpoints, or to handle vendor-specific control transfers on endpoint zero.  I am not familiar with the STM32 USB libraries, but you should be able to identify the core component of it that implements control transfers and IN and OUT endpoints, without doing anything specific to a device class.  That is the component that you would need to learn how to use.
5. By default, you should use WinUSB instead of USB CDC ACM.  The only reason to use USB CDC ACM is if your device is actually a serial port or if you want to make it easier for people to talk to your device in a variety of programming languages and environments.  Most programming languages support serial ports, but the user would still have to write the code on top of that that generates your particular command format, so it doesn't actually give you that much.  One problem with USB CDC ACM is that if the device gets disconnected while you have a handle open to it, and then it gets reconnected, the various USB CDC ACM drivers can often get into a bad state.  In particular, usbser.sys prior to Windows 10 does not handle this well, and you usually have to unplug and replug the device to make the COM port usable again.  USB CDC ACM uses bulk endpoints for its data transfer, so there is no latency guarantee.  With WinUSB, you have the option to use Interrupt endpoints so that you can be guaranteed to always have one packet transferred for every USB frame.

Comment: Would it be correct verbiage to say that one can use WinUSB to implement a *Custom* USB class?

Comment: Re - `you should consider sending your data as a control transfer or series of control transfers on endpoint 0. Control transfers have a built-in concept of a request and a response to the request.` The USB 2.0 spec says that Control Transfers are "best effort" (section 5.5). Bulk Transfers have "guaranteed delivery" (section 5.8). Looks to me like I should stick with Bulk Transfers - or am I missing something?

Comment: I think you're comparing different properties of the two transfer types.  As section 5.5 explains, "best effort" means you don't get a guarantee for the bandwidth or access frequency when using control transfers.  Section 5.8 says the same thing about bulk transfers using different words: it says you don't get guarantees on the bus latency of bandwidth.  In my experience, both of them have guaranteed delivery; that's the whole point of having the ACK packets and data toggling.

Comment: I posted a follow-up question. http://stackoverflow.com/q/38981712/1995714

Answer (score 9):

WinUSB consists of two parts:

- WinUsb.sys is a kernel-mode driver that can be installed as either a filter or function driver, above the protocol drivers in a USB device’s kernel-mode device stack.
- WinUsb.dll is a user-mode DLL that exposes the WinUSB API. Applications can use this API to communicate with WinUsb.sys when it is installed as a device’s function driver.
  WinUSB API—exposed by WinUSB.dll. WinUSB is included in the Windows Driver Kit (WDK) in the form of a co-installer package, WinUSBCoInstaller.dll, located in WinDDK\BuildNumber\Redist\Winusb.

To use the WinUSB API in an application:

- Include WinUsb.h
- Add WinUsb.lib to the list of libraries that are linked to your application.
- Usb100.h contains declarations for some useful macros.
- Use the device interface GUID to obtain the device path. The correct GUID is the one that you specified in the INF that was used to install WinUsb.sys.
- Get a handle to the device information set by passing the device interface GUID that you defined in the INF to SetupDiGetClassDevs. The function returns an HDEVINFO handle.
- Call SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces to enumerate the system’s device interfaces and obtain information on your device interface.
- Call SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail to get detailed data for the device interface.
- Call the GetDevicePath function to obtain the device path.
- Pass the device path to CreateFile to obtain a file handle for the device. Use *ReadFile and WriteFile to communicate with device*.
- Pass the file handle to WinUsb_Initialize to initialize WinUSB and obtain a WinUSB handle. You use the device’s WinUSB handle to identify the device when you call WinUSB API functions, not the device’s file handle.

For more advanced solutions - use functions:

- WinUsb_QueryDeviceInformation to obtain the device’s speed.
- WinUsb_QueryInterfaceSettings to obtain the corresponding interface descriptors. The WinUSB handle corresponds to the first interface.
- WinUsb_QueryPipe gets information about each endpoint.
- WinUsb_WritePipe writes the buffer to the device  - default behavior: zero-length writes are forwarded down the stack. If the transfer length is greater than a maximum transfer length, WinUSB divides the request into smaller requests of maximum transfer length and submits them serially.
- more functions and info: http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/c/5/9c5b2167-8017-4bae-9fde-d599bac8184a/winusb_howto.docx

For debugging purposes You probably need:
 winusbtrace_tool  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/usbcoreblog/2010/02/05/how-to-generate-and-view-a-winusb-debug-trace-log/; 
Wireshark https://www.wireshark.org with USBPcap plugin.

Other Example:
http://searchingforbit.blogspot.com/2012/04/winusb-communication-with-stm32-part-1.html.
Sample template comes with Visual Studio.

You need also have knowledge of writing .inf files.

Another easy way to communicate with USB - libusb-win32 https://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb-win32/

My simple example console application sends small (for keep-alive) chunks of data to device:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <SetupAPI.h>
#include <Hidsdi.h> 
#include <devguid.h> 
#include <winusb.h>
#include <usb.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "hid.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "setupapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "winusb.lib")
#include <iUString.h> 


iString<char> DevicePath;
bool                    WinusbHandle_Open=false;
bool                    DeviceHandle_Open = false;
WINUSB_INTERFACE_HANDLE WinusbHandle;
HANDLE                  DeviceHandle;
UCHAR usb_out_buffer[64];
DEFINE_GUID(GUID_DEVCLASS_WINUSB, 0x88bae032L, 0x5a81, 0x49f0, 0xbc, 0x3d, 0xa4, 0xff, 0x13, 0x82, 0x16, 0xd6);
DEFINE_GUID(GUID_DEVCLASS_STL, 0xf177724dL, 0x74d3, 0x430e, 0x86, 0xb5, 0xf0, 0x36, 0x89, 0x10, 0xeb, 0x23);
GUID winusb_guid;
GUID stl_guid;

bool connectusb();
void  disconnectusb();




int main()
{
    DWORD n;
    DWORD   numEvents;
    HANDLE rHnd;    

WinusbHandle_Open = false;
DeviceHandle_Open = false;
winusb_guid = GUID_DEVCLASS_WINUSB;
stl_guid = GUID_DEVCLASS_STL;
usb_out_buffer[0] = 0;
usb_out_buffer[1] = 1;
usb_out_buffer[2] = 2;
usb_out_buffer[3] = 3;

ULONG bytesWritten;
ULONG timeout;
timeout = 100;
rHnd = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

WinUsb_SetPipePolicy(WinusbHandle, 0x01, PIPE_TRANSFER_TIMEOUT, sizeof(ULONG), &timeout);

timeout = TRUE;
WinUsb_SetPipePolicy(WinusbHandle, 0x01, AUTO_CLEAR_STALL, sizeof(ULONG), &timeout);


timeout = TRUE;
WinUsb_SetPipePolicy(WinusbHandle, 0x01, RAW_IO, sizeof(ULONG), &timeout);//Bypasses queuing and error handling to boost performance for multiple read requests.


while (true)
{
if ((!WinusbHandle_Open) || (!WinusbHandle_Open)) { if (!connectusb())Sleep(2000); }
if ((!WinusbHandle_Open) || (!WinusbHandle_Open))continue;

bytesWritten = 0;
if (!WinUsb_WritePipe(WinusbHandle, 0x01, &usb_out_buffer[0], 2, &bytesWritten, NULL))
{
    n = GetLastError();
disconnectusb();
}
Sleep(2000);
}
disconnectusb();
return 0;
}




bool connectusb()
{
    BOOL                             bResult = FALSE;
    HDEVINFO                         deviceInfo;
    SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA         interfaceData;
    PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA detailData = NULL;
    DWORD n;
    SP_DEVINFO_DATA devinfo;
    BYTE devdetailbuffer[4096];
    bool found;

    deviceInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&stl_guid, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);
    if (deviceInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) { return false; }

    found = false;
    for (n = 0;; n++)
    {

        interfaceData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);

        if (!SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(deviceInfo, NULL, &stl_guid, n, &interfaceData))
        {
            n = GetLastError();
            break;
        }




        detailData = (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA)devdetailbuffer;
        detailData->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);
        devinfo.cbSize = sizeof(devinfo);
        if (!SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(deviceInfo, &interfaceData, detailData, sizeof(devdetailbuffer), NULL, &devinfo)) { printf("SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail: %u\n", GetLastError()); break; }
        if (IsEqualGUID(devinfo.ClassGuid, winusb_guid))
        {
            if ((-1 != iStrPos(detailData->DevicePath, "VID_0483")) || (-1 != iStrPos(detailData->DevicePath, "vid_0483")))
            {
                if ((-1 != iStrPos(detailData->DevicePath, "PID_576B")) || (-1 != iStrPos(detailData->DevicePath, "pid_576b")))
                {

                    DevicePath = detailData->DevicePath;
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }



SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(deviceInfo);
if (!found)return false;


DeviceHandle = CreateFile(DevicePath.Buffer() ,
    GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,
    FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
    NULL);

if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == DeviceHandle) {
    n = GetLastError();
}

if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == DeviceHandle) return false;
DeviceHandle_Open = true;



if (!WinUsb_Initialize(DeviceHandle, &WinusbHandle))
 {
     n = GetLastError();
     CloseHandle(DeviceHandle); DeviceHandle_Open = false;
     return false;
 }



WinusbHandle_Open = true;
return true;
}

void  disconnectusb()
{
    if (WinusbHandle_Open) { WinUsb_Free(WinusbHandle); WinusbHandle_Open = false; }
    if (DeviceHandle_Open) { CloseHandle(DeviceHandle); DeviceHandle_Open = false; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I also have to do your exact same requirement:  PC <==> STM
Microsoft has lots of documentation on WinUSB.  Here is what I've seen that answers your questions...

Custom USB device sample
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CustomUsbDeviceAccess

Developing Windows applications for USB devices  --  C# AND VB
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/developing-windows-applications-that-communicate-with-a-usb-device

Windows desktop app for a USB device
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/windows-desktop-app-for-a-usb-device

How to Access a USB Device by Using WinUSB Functions
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/using-winusb-api-to-communicate-with-a-usb-device

Developing Windows drivers for USB host controllers
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/developing-windows-drivers-for-usb-host-controllers

Windows.Devices.Usb Windows.Devices.Usb Namespace
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.usb

Answer (score 0):

I solved this request so I understand your intention is about to **make your firmware could be enumerated as a WINUSB (winusb generic driver) device** automatically by Windows while plugging-in.

I believe it'd be clear if you have a demo and code so I made one for you :)

My **KEIL project** using the **STM32F4 Discovery** board working with **WINUSB** as an **USB CDC device**.

You can see more information and have **the source code from [my GitHub](https://github.com/MouChiaHung/STM32F4).**

For deploying WINUSB it's necessary to **manually** modify USB device and middleware layers source code in the KEIL project.
You can focus on **usbd_ctlreq.c, usbd_cdc.c and usbd_desc.c** to have a comparison with origins generated by CubeMX.