# Do USB Control Transfers guarantee delivery?

Tags: usb

[USB 2.0 specifies](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/usb20_docs/) 4 types of transfers (in section 5.4 Transfer Types):

- Control Transfers
- Isochronous Transfers
- Interrupt Transfers
- Bulk Transfers

Section 5.8 says that Bulk Transfers provide:

> - Access to the USB on a bandwidth-available basis
> - Retry of transfers, in the case of occasional delivery failure due to errors on the bus
> - **Guaranteed delivery of data** but no guarantee of bandwidth or latency

(Emphasis mine.)

I don't see a similar statement for Control Transfers. Do they also guarantee delivery? If not, how are users expected to handle failures?

Please provide a citation(s) to support your answer.

Comment: Should I move this question to [EE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The USB specification provides robust error detection and recovery for control transfers.  The control transfer will either be completed or the USB host will know that it failed, and I think that's what "guaranteed delivery" is supposed to mean.  This is important because control transfers are used to set up the device when you plug it into a computer and they are also used for many important purposes by the various USB device classes (e.g. they are used to set the baud rate of a serial port on a USB CDC ACM device).

From section 5.5.5 of the USB 2.0 specification:

> The USB provides robust error detection and recovery/retransmission for errors that occur during control transfers. Transmitters and receivers can remain synchronized with regard to where they are in a control transfer and recover with minimum effort. Retransmission of Data and Status packets can be detected by a receiver via data retry indicators in the packet. A transmitter can reliably determine that its corresponding receiver has successfully accepted a transmitted packet by information returned in a handshake to the packet. The protocol allows for distinguishing a retransmitted packet from its original packet except for a control Setup packet. Setup packets may be retransmitted due to a transmission error; however, Setup packets cannot indicate that a packet is an original or a retried transmission.

The only transfer type without guaranteed delivery is isochronous.  Also, the start of frame (SOF) packets don't have guaranteed delivery.