# Is USB CDC communication guaranteed?

Tags: usb, stm32

**TLDR version:**

Working with a Windows or Linux PC communicating with an STM32 micro via a USB port (USB 1.1) configured for Full Speed and the USB device configured as a CDC (Virtual COM Port) - all using the STM HAL libraries - when data is written to the device via write()/WriteFile() calls, is that data guaranteed to arrive intact on the STM32?  (Assume everything is configured correctly, I'm not writing packets bigger than the buffer sizes and I'm not trying to write whilst a transfer is already in progress).

I've found this answer, which suggests that they are, but this relates to USB 2.0: [Do USB Control Transfers guarantee delivery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38981712/do-usb-control-transfers-guarantee-delivery/38982617)

**Background:**

I've inherited a project from my predecessor.  The code that has been used for the communication protocol has been modified from other internal sources from fairly old legacy code that worked with non-USB hardware to carry the signals.

The data packets that are actually sent can potentially be twice as big as the buffer being transmitted, as two 8-bit values are reserved (one is a packet start byte) and these then get 'escaped' into 2byte values.  In addition, each packet contains a 16-bit CRC.  In all the testing I've performed, no errors in transmission have ever occurred.  I've had to 'fake' errors to test the code path through the comms code as I'm making changes.

We're now in a situation where we'd like to offer a feature to our customers that would push the data throughput to its limit.  The feature works, again no transmission errors are picked up by the anticipated packet start byte or CRC arrangement.  The problem is, if the packets contain either of the reserved values, than the transmission speed effectively drops as the data has to be expanded.

In addition to the expanding packets, there is also the overhead of having to check the incoming packets, un-escape them and also calculate the CRC.

So, if the USB CDC protocol guarantees that the data will arrive intact (I've already encountered and handled the 64byte chunks), then I can do away with the start byte, escaped data and the CRC and get a guaranteed fixed transmission speed with faster processing speed on the receiving end (which occurs in an interrupt), too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  CDC ACM virtual COM ports use bulk endpoints to transport their data.  You can verify this by looking at your device's USB endpoint descriptors.  The behavior of bulk endpoints is defined by the USB specification.  Like most endpoint types, bulk endpoints use CRCs to ensure the data was transmitted correctly, and there is a retry mechanism built into USB to retry sending the data if there was an error.  Of course, this doesn't prevent badly-written firmware or software from throwing away the data by accident.

Separately: if you are designing a serial protocol, it's a really good idea to have a way for the sender to get the receiver into a known state, just in case there was some other software talking to the device previously and it sent invalid data.  Usually there is a special byte (or byte sequence) you can send that will signal the start of a packet.  Another idea is to use the out-of-band control signals that CDC ACM offers, like the "Set Control Line State" or the "Send Break" commands.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to David Grayson's answer, it should be pointed out that the entire communication chain from host's serial API via the USB bulk endpoint to the STM32 HAL library has flow control mechanisms. They guarantee that the sender is blocked until the next stage can accept the data.

Even if you submit more data to `WriteFile()` than the buffer sizes along the chain can hold, no data will be lost. It will be transmitted in smaller packages and at a speed that the receiver can accept it.

The flow control mechanisms are inherent to `WriteFile()`, to USB bulk endpoints and to the STM32 HAL library (and not related to serial flow control like RTS/CTS).

The same also applies in the other direction if the STM32 codes properly checks if the return code of `CDC_Transmit_FS()`.